# python script that connects with vsftpd

Tags: python, ftp, sftp, paramiko, vsftpd

I have the following issue... i need to connect to sftp(vsftpd) through python script, upload a file and download it. So far i have created ftp server with vsftpd but i cannot connect. If i use the terminal(ftp localhost) i can log in without any problems. Please advise how i should proceed.

Here is my python script:
http://codepaste.net/omysxu

and here is the config file of vsftpd:
http://codepaste.net/1qrrdf

The thing that i am trying to do is.. set up a ftp server, then i should have 2 scripts(or 1) which will have to upload file via ssh then download it in another dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vsftpd is a FTP server and can not be accessed with the SFTP protocol. FTP, SFTP and FTPS are often confused:

- FTP = file transfer protocol (RFC959) - supported by vsftpd
- FTPS = extension for using TLS with FTP (RFC4217) - supported by vsftpd
- SFTP = file transfer using the SSH protocol - not supported by vsftpd, you need SSH for this.

Comment: Thanks, that answer my question, but if you have some guides for me on how to create those scripts.